Using PreparedStatement with Snowflake/SnowQL RLIKE clause not working due to quotations " vs '
When inserting into a prepared statement using the setString() method it forces double quotes around the value. Snowflake/SnowQL requires single quotes when using RLIKE and other methods in its where clauses.
For example:
org_id rlike ?
with
ps.setString(1, "123")
becomes
org_id rlike "123"
Which is invalid syntax. The desired result is
org_id rlike '123'
Any ideas on how to get around this problem? I have other double quotes in this query so replacing all of the double quotes with single is not a solution.
Versions:
Java 8
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.snowflake</groupId>
    <artifactId>snowflake-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.14.4</version>
</dependency>

Bad double quotes
Good single quotes
-- Edit Workaround found --
For my use case all the string values are numbers, so I was able to CAST(<field> as INTEGER) as "NEW-NAME".
I could then use that in my where clause with PreparedStatement's
ps.setInt() method.
Not a solution to this exact problem but a solution

What's rlike? If you mean like then you can't use bind variables (i.e. a PreparedStatement parameter) with that anyway. It might not complain but it won't be 'prepared'

rlike is the regex variant of like
Due to the problem I need to be using regex and not just  like unfortunately
When using other database jdbc connectors I am able to use PreparedStatement parameters

OK. For the reasons I gave, you can't use a PreparedStatement with any kind of LIKE with parameters. I would use a standard Statement with something like String sql = stub.concat("'%s'".formatted(value));

Do you know if that is Snowflake specific problem?
For example we use PreparedStatement for Hadoop connections and other data sources with rlike and like

Unfortunately I know nothing about Snowflake. But as I said, even if it works, it's a theoretical mistake to use parameters to LIKE

Is that a standard? I havent heard of that before. Just curious as to why its a mistake even if theoretical

@g00se Why? It would provide a protection against an injection attack, which your suggestion is vulnerable to.
